# Facebook Page plugin dark theme

Tags: facebook

I'd like to change colors of [new Facebook Page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin). Unfortunatelly I can't find setting for it.

In [Like button plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) it is possible to set **light** or **dark** theme by `data-colorscheme` attribute.

Current default Page plugin:

[image]

My desired color scheme (approximately):

[image]

Comment: We don't have support for dark theme on the new plugin. 

Please subscribe to the bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/653853764748534/

We'll update on the bug report if we change this in future.